# How to download jdk8 via PowerShell and accept the Oracle Binary Code License Agreement

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to download JDK8 on Windows Server 2016 Core using `Start-BitsTransfer`.

When executing the command (shown at the picture) I get a redirection error. Not accepting the license can also be an issue, how can I accept the license?

[image: Redirection Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Chocolatey script that downloads the JDK](https://chocolatey.org/packages/jdk8/) (expand tools\common.ps1) uses cookies to accept the license:

`$dummy = $client.Headers.Add('Cookie', 'gpw_e24=http://www.oracle.com; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie')`

That does not seem possible to do with Start-BitsTransfer since it doesn't have fine-grained control over things like HTTP headers, but `System.Net.WebClient` [does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) through the [Headers property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers(v=vs.110).aspx).

So if you can use webclient instead of Start-BitsTransfer, do that.

Comment: `Chocolatey` made this much easier. Thank you! :)